# How can I add data to my model containing User as a foreign key from a custom-made form in django?

Tags: python, django, backend

Here, when I try to add a new note with a user logged in, I want that note to have its user-field filled with the current logged in user. So I wrote `user=request.user`  But error arises: UNIQUE constraint failed: mynotes_note.user_id
Here are my files:

models.py

```
class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

addForm.py

```
from django import forms

    class addForm(forms.Form):

        title = forms.CharField(max_length=50,
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class':'form-control'
            }))
        desc = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class':'form-control'
        }))
```

Here, I used this way instead of using Meta class just to apply some bootstrap effects to the form fields

views.py

```
def addView(request):
    if request.user.is_active:
        if request.method=="POST":
            form=addForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                newNote = Note(user=request.user,title=request.POST['title'],desc=request.POST['desc'])
                newNote.save()
                return redirect('home')
        else:
                form=addForm()
                args={'form':form}
                return render(request,'mynotes/add.html',args)
    else:
        return redirect('home')
```

Comment: It has no sense unless they are something we don't see in your code, for example, may be, you wrote a constraint on foreign key or something similar that now is not present ( by it is on database). Also, you should to avoid use `request.Post`, use `form.cleaned_data`

Comment: Would you please rewrite this code making necessary changes using form.cleaned_data?....I am just a beginner here and I am not able to add bootstrap effects to my custom form if I use cleaned_data method

Comment: I guess no. A good idea for you is to  go docs and learn how to do it. Or start a course or just read tutorials.

Comment: I found my error. It was in my html file. Sorry for the inconvenience!